# Iterate list over a dictionary values and print matching key,value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d1 = {'A' : [1,2], 'B':[2,3,4],'C':[4,1,3,2], 'D':[5,6], 'E':[7,2], 'F':[8,1],'G':[1,3,4,2]}

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
d ={}

for i in l1:
 for key,value in d1.():
   for j in value:
     if i in value[j]:
       d.setdefault(key,[]).append(i)
```

Expected output:

- a 1
- c 1
- g 1
- a 2
- b 2
- c 2
- e 2

but I am getting an error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

To give a gist about what I am trying to accomplish is I have list of links that needs to be checked in template and return the template name along with link.

Here the template name is key & the numbers r links which is value

Thank you in advance

Comment: `for key,value in d1.():` should be `for key,value in d1.items():`

Comment: sorry, yeah. Thank you for pointing it out,I missed it but still. It's throwing IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `j ` will not be an index, so `value[j]` doesn't make much sense. `j` will be an actual element from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I edited my original anwser to match your clarification:

```
d1 = {'A' : [1,2], 'B':[2,3,4],'C':[4,1,3,2], 'D':[5,6], 'E':[7,2], 'F':[8,1],'G':[1,3,4,2]}
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
d = []

for i in l1:
    for k, v in d1.items():
        if i in v:
            d.append((k,i))
```

`print(d)` outputs:

```
[('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('F', 1), ('G', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('E', 2), ('G', 2), ('B', 3), ('C', 3), ('G', 3), ('B', 4), ('C', 4), ('G', 4), ('D', 5), ('D', 6), ('E', 7), ('F', 8)]
```

Comment: Thank you @Dawid Januszkiewicz
Please can you guide me on how to print the same output in list as below basically a list
a 1
c 1
g 1
a 2
b 2
c 2
e 2

Comment: You'd have to use a list instead of a dict for 'd', and then the last line would change to d.append((k, i))

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you intend to do?

```
d1 = {
'A' : [1,2],
'B':[2,3,4],
'C':[4,1,3,2],
'D':[5,6], 
'E':[7,2], 
'F':[8,1],
'G':[1,3,4,2]}

l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
d ={}

for i in l1:
 for key,value in d1.items():
   for j in value:
     if i is j:
       d.setdefault(key,[]).append(i)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 2], 'C': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'F': [1, 8], 'G': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [2, 3, 4], 'E': [2, 7], 'D': [5, 6]}
```